# How to bypass dimmer switch?

Tags: dimmer, bypass

I bought this lamp from "Ferm Living" that comes with a built-in 3-level dimmer mode which I don't like. I rather would like to connect the lamp to a switched power socket and whenever the power socket is on, the lamp shall be on in its brightest setting (i.e., not dimmed). I took the attached photos - any hint what I have to do to achieve this? Can I somehow bypass the entire PCB board or do I have to rewire/ solder something? I am quite inexperience in this kind of work...

[image]

Comment: How does the dimming work? (ie what is the defaut state, how do you go brighter/dimmer?). I think modifying the "button" or whatever way the dimming is controled is probably the only way that might be safe to bypass the dimming (only might, I can't tell if it will be until I know how it's done, it might not be possible or not safe). Please also provide a picture of the bottom of the PCB. Another alternative might be to replae the PCB by another one : for this, we would need the reference written on LED ruban (and the number of LEDs on it)

Comment: Changing the level of dimming works by using the incorporated switch in the power cable, i.e. lamp needs to be connected to a power source and only when the power is on, you can use the switch that you have to press multiple times (on/off) to switch the dimming modes. The LED ribbon states "2835-90LED". I also think replacing the PCB by another LED driver (w/o dimming capabilities) is the safest way to go but unsure which one would be the right one (Volts/Watts)...

Comment: It will be very difficult to find a 270v (!) low power LED driver. Typically these are low voltage for safety reasons. I suggest removing that LED strip (which is junk anyway) and putting in a 12v LED strip of the desired brightness.

Comment: @user1850479, how do you know it is 270v?

Comment: @Airlike1 90 LEDs times 3v per LED. Plus it's running off of rectified 220AC with no transformer or switching regulator to step down the voltage so you'd expect something close to that just from the topology.

Answer (score 1):

That appears to generate a constant current by pushing mains directly through a capacitor and then rectifying and smoothing. I would guess the light levels are achieved by having another couple of caps "short" the current limited mains after it passes through the square cap.

Basically - don't touch it. Having non isolated mains on a board is potentially a serious hazard if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks. I would have thought that replacing the board with an LED driver like this one but I am not sure whether this is the right route to go... https://images.pearl.ch/images/product_images/original_images/zx1372_1.jpg

Comment: @Airlike1 Again, this is just a guess and assuming your mains is 220VAC and 50Hz, the raw current will be around 160mA through the capacitor, so that is likely what a constant current LED driver needs to deliver

Comment: Thanks. I will look further into it or bring it to a local shop/expert.

Comment: You might have problems given the legal liabilities involved. It's not something I would do for anyone